# Extend class from external declaration file?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with the uppy library but it the declaration files are not up-to-date. I'm trying to create a new UI Plugin:

```
import Uppy, { UIPlugin, UppyFile, type I18n } from "@uppy/core";

export default class MyCustomPlugin extends UIPlugin {
    constructor(uppy: Uppy, opts: any) {
        super(uppy, opts);
        this.initI18n() // method does not exist in the d.ts file of uppy
    }
}
```

Now I try to declare the method in my own `uppy.d.ts` file but it does not work:

```
declare module "@uppy/core" {
  export type I18n = (
    key: string,
    options?: { smart_count?: number }
  ) => string;

  export class BasePlugin<
    TOptions extends PluginOptions,
    TPluginState extends object
  > {
    id: string;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    uppy: Uppy;

    type: string;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    constructor(uppy: Uppy, opts?: TOptions);

    setOptions(update: Partial<TOptions>): void;

    getPluginState(): Record<string, unknown>;

    setPluginState(
      update: IndexedObject<TPluginState>
    ): Record<string, unknown>;

    install(): void;

    uninstall(): void;

    i18nInit(): void;
  }

  export class UIPlugin<
    TOptions extends UIPluginOptions,
    TPluginState extends object
  > extends BasePlugin<TOptions, TPluginState> {
    id: string;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    uppy: Uppy;

    type: string;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    constructor(uppy: Uppy, opts?: TOptions);

    update(state?: Record<string, unknown>): void;

    getTargetPlugin(
      target: PluginTarget
    ): UIPlugin<TOptions, TPluginState> | undefined;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
    mount(target: PluginTarget, plugin: UIPlugin<TOptions, TPluginState>): void;

    render(state: Record<string, unknown>): void;

    addTarget<TPlugin extends UIPlugin<TOptions, TPluginState>>(
      plugin: TPlugin
    ): void;

    unmount(): void;

    onMount(): void;

    onUnmount(): void;
  }
}
```

What's the correct way to do this?